# Passing Connectionstring as parameter in SSRS through URL

Tags: url, reporting-services, asp-classic, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on an application using Classic ASP and SQL Server 2008 R2. We are using SSRS for the reports. Now the datasource changes depending on the user. I have been using a parameter for the connectionstring. It is working fine but the problem is the connectionstring shows in the URL. Is there a way to hide it? Or is there a better way.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - change the method on your form to `POST` and use the `Request.Form` syntax instead of `Request.QueryString`:

```html
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="myPage.asp">
    <label for="txtBox">Type something</label>
    <input type="text" id="txtBox" name="txtBox" />
</form>
```

```vb
<%
Dim value
value = Cstr(Request.Form("txtBox"))
If value <> "" then
    'Do your processing
End if
%>
```

**-- EDIT --**

To be honest, though, I would not store my connection string on my form like this.  You'd be far better off storing it in an Application level variable, like so:

```
Application("CON_STRING") = "...blahblahblah..."
```

This should be stored in the `Application_OnStart` event of the [`Global.asa`](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_globalasa.asp)* file.

*
*Apologies for the link to w3schools - it was the best at the time!*

**-- EDIT 2 --**

Try using an `iframe` to display the info...

```
<form id="frmRender" action="ABCD/ReportServer?/Reports/rptSalesReport.rpt"; method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="rs:Command" value="Render">
    <input type="hidden" name="rc:LinkTarget" value="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="rs:Format" value="HTML4.0">
    <input type="hidden" name="rc:Parameters" value="False">
    <input type="hidden" name="ConnectionString" value="<%=Session("ConnectionString")%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="StartDate" value="<%=StartDate%>">
    <input type="hidden" name="EndDate" value="<%=EndDate%>">
    <a id="linkInfo" href="javascript:generateSsrs();">Generate Report</a>

    <iframe id="ssrsReport" class="reportHeightWidth"></iframe>
</form >

<script language="javascript">
    function genreateSsrs() {
        document.getElementById("ssrsReport").src = "ABCD/ReportServer?/Reports/rptSalesReport.rpt?rs:Command=Render&rc:LinkTarget=top&rs:Format=HTML4.0&rc:Parameters=False&ConnectionString=<%=Server.URLEncode(Session("ConnectionString"))%>&StartDate=<%=StartDate%>&EndDate=<%=EndDate%>";
    }
</script>
```

That's a rough version, but it's untested, so may need some tweaks.

Comment: Thanks Paul,
But the thing is I am passing the connectionstring from my application to the SSRS Report using the report parameter. And as far as I know I am using the post method but it still shows.

Comment: Here is the sample @Paul

Comment: Here is sample @Paul
 <FORM id="frmRender" action="http://ABCD/ReportServer?/Reports/rptSalesReport.rpt" method="post" target="_blank">
   <INPUT type="hidden" name="rs:Command" value="Render">
   <INPUT type="hidden" name="rc:LinkTarget" value="_blank">
   <INPUT type="hidden" name="rs:Format" value="HTML4.0">
   <INPUT type="hidden" name="rc:Parameters" value="False">
   <INPUT type="hidden" name="ConnectionString" value="<%=Session("ConnectionString")%>">
   <INPUT type="hidden" name="StartDate" value="<%=StartDate%>">
   <INPUT type="hidden" name="EndDate" value="<%=EndDate%>">  
</FORM>

Comment: @Programmer666: Try generating the SSRS page in an `iframe` in your page, that way the query string will never be seen.

Comment: @Programmer666: Put an `id` in for each of the controls (rather than just a name).

Comment: Thanks @paul but it still shows. Paul is there a way to pass Reporting Server Credentials through classic ASP.

Comment: Still shows?!  It shouldn't show if you pass it into an `iframe` - the frame shouldn't display the address at all unless you right click the contents and view the page info.

Comment: Hi @Programmer666, don't know if it's any help, but I did [find this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cc864bc8-1225-489c-b901-8016d656a5db/how-to-access-a-ssrs-report-from-a-classic-asp-page?forum=sqlreportingservices).  Could be useful and follows the iframe route.

Comment: Hey Thanks @Paul. But I am really confused with all this I am basically an SSRS/SQL Developer. Classic ASP is not really my cup of tea but I guess I still have to do a job. I should probably be taking it from scratch. Will it be asking too much if I ask you to guide me through the basic steps.

Answer (score 0):

In you code, use the below code

```
 ="Data Source="+Parameters!DatabaseServerName.Value+";Initial Catalog="&Parameters!DatabaseCatalogName.Value
```