# Calling SSRS Report from Classic ASP

Tags: asp.net, post, reporting-services, asp-classic

I was in need of calling SSRS Reports from classic ASP. After looking around I found that it was suggested that SSRS reports should be called using ASP.Net so I managed to use ASP.Net with my classic ASP application using session transfer.(By saving sessions to the database redirecting from classic ASP to ASP.Net). However while redirecting i am passing parameters as querystring (Using Response.Redirect). I am wondering when the parameters will be really big will that create any problem.(Like select 1000 customer ids each five characters long).
I would like to use POST method as I believe it is better and more secure.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Anyone .....Please help. I desperately need help.

Comment: Can'y you just embed SSRS reports using an iFrame and embed parameters in the URL that way using jQuery?

Comment: That's what I said in your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25864031/passing-connectionstring-as-parameter-in-ssrs-through-url), Programmer666.

Comment: Well if I use IFrame. How can i pass Reporting Server Credentials?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this that may help you.

[https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/microsoft.public.sqlserver.reportingsvcs/_BX59sIW1gw][1]